# SQL Server: Query fast, but slow from procedure

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

A query runs fast:

```
DECLARE @SessionGUID uniqueidentifier
SET @SessionGUID = 'BCBA333C-B6A1-4155-9833-C495F22EA908'

SELECT *
FROM Report_Opener
WHERE SessionGUID = @SessionGUID
ORDER BY CurrencyTypeOrder, Rank
```

**subtree cost: 0.502**

But putting the same SQL in a stored procedure runs slow, and with a totally different execution plan

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ViewOpener @SessionGUID uniqueidentifier AS
SELECT *
FROM Report_Opener
WHERE SessionGUID = @SessionGUID
ORDER BY CurrencyTypeOrder, Rank

EXECUTE ViewOpener @SessionGUID
```

**Subtree cost: 19.2**

I've run

```
sp_recompile ViewOpener
```

And it still runs the same (badly), and I've also changed the stored 
procedure to

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ViewOpener @SessionGUID uniqueidentifier AS
SELECT *, 'recompile please'
FROM Report_Opener
WHERE SessionGUID = @SessionGUID
ORDER BY CurrencyTypeOrder, Rank
```

And back again, trying to really trick it into recompiling.

I've dropped and recreated the stored procedure in order to get it to generate a new plan.

I've tried forcing recompiles, **and prevent parameter sniffing**, by using a decoy variable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ViewOpener @SessionGUID uniqueidentifier AS

DECLARE @SessionGUIDbitch uniqueidentifier
SET @SessionGUIDbitch = @SessionGUID

SELECT *
FROM Report_Opener
WHERE SessionGUID = @SessionGUIDbitch
ORDER BY CurrencyTypeOrder, Rank
```

I've also tried defining the stored procedure **`WITH RECOMPILE`**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ViewOpener @SessionGUID uniqueidentifier 
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
SELECT *
FROM Report_Opener
WHERE SessionGUID = @SessionGUID
ORDER BY CurrencyTypeOrder, Rank
```

So that it's plan is never cached, and I've tried forcing a recompile at execute:

```
EXECUTE ViewOpener @SessionGUID WITH RECOMPILE
```

Which didn't help.

I've tried converting the procedure to dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ViewOpener @SessionGUID uniqueidentifier 
WITH RECOMPILE AS
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT *
   FROM Report_OpenerTest
   WHERE SessionGUID = @SessionGUID
   ORDER BY CurrencyTypeOrder, Rank'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString,
N'@SessionGUID uniqueidentifier',
@SessionGUID
```

Which didn't help.

The entity "`Report_Opener`" is a view, which is not indexed. The view only references underlying tables. No table contains computed columns, indexed or otherwise.

For the hell of it I tried creating the view with

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFER ON
```

That didn't fix it.

How is it that

- the query is fast
- moving the query to a view, and selecting from the view is fast
- selecting from the view from a stored procedure is 40x slower?

I tried moving the definition of the view directly into the stored procedure (violating 3 business rules, and breaking an important encapsulation), and that makes it only about 6x slower.

Why is the stored procedure version so slow? What can possibly account for SQL Server running ad-hoc SQL faster than a different kind of ad-hoc SQL?

I'd really rather not

- embed the SQL in code
- change the code at all

  ```
  Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2050 (Intel X86)
  Mar  7 2008 21:29:56
  Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation
  Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
  ```

But what can account for SQL Server being unable to run as fast as SQL Sever running a query, if not parameter sniffing.

---

My next attempt will be to have `StoredProcedureA` call `StoredProcedureB` call `StoredProcedureC` call `StoredProcedureD` to query the view.

And failing that, have the stored procedure call a stored procedure, call a UDF, call a UDF, call a stored procedure, call a UDF to query the view.

---

To sum up, the following run fast from QA, but slow when put into a stored procedure:

The original:

```
--Runs fine outside of a stored procedure
SELECT *
FROM Report_OpenerTest
WHERE SessionGUID = @SessionGUID
ORDER BY CurrencyTypeOrder, Rank
```

`sp_executesql`:

```
--Runs fine outside of a stored procedure
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT *
FROM Report_OpenerTest
WHERE SessionGUID = @SessionGUID
ORDER BY CurrencyTypeOrder, Rank'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString,
        N'@SessionGUID uniqueidentifier',
        @SessionGUID
```

`EXEC(@sql)`:

```
--Runs fine outside of a stored procedure
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
SET @sql = N'SELECT *
FROM Report_OpenerTest
WHERE SessionGUID = '''+CAST(@SessionGUID AS varchar(50))+'''
ORDER BY CurrencyTypeOrder, Rank'

EXEC(@sql)
```

---

Execution Plans

The **good** plan:

```
      |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Expr1020] ASC, [Currencies].[Rank] ASC))
           |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1020]=If ([Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctCanadianCash') then 1 else If ([Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctMiscellaneous') then 2 else If ([Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctTokens') then 3 else If ([Currencies].[CurrencyType]
                |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Openers].[OpenerGUID]))
                     |--Filter(WHERE:((([Currencies].[IsActive]<>0 AND [Currencies].[OnOpener]<>0) AND ((((((([Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctUSCoin' OR [Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctMiscellaneousUS') OR [Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctUSCash') OR [Currencies].
                     |    |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Currencies].[CurrencyGUID], [Openers].[OpenerGUID]) WITH PREFETCH)
                     |         |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join)
                     |         |    |--Bookmark Lookup(BOOKMARK:([Bmk1016]), OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[Windows]))
                     |         |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Openers].[WindowGUID]))
                     |         |    |         |--Bookmark Lookup(BOOKMARK:([Bmk1014]), OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[Openers]))
                     |         |    |         |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[Openers].[IX_Openers_SessionGUID]), SEEK:([Openers].[SessionGUID]=[@SessionGUID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                     |         |    |         |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[Windows].[IX_Windows]), SEEK:([Windows].[WindowGUID]=[Openers].[WindowGUID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                     |         |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[Currencies].[IX_Currencies_CurrencyType]))
                     |         |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[OpenerDetails].[IX_OpenerDetails_OpenerGUIDCurrencyGUID]), SEEK:([OpenerDetails].[OpenerGUID]=[Openers].[OpenerGUID] AND [OpenerDetails].[CurrencyGUID]=[Currenc
                     |--Hash Match(Cache, HASH:([Openers].[OpenerGUID]), RESIDUAL:([Openers].[OpenerGUID]=[Openers].[OpenerGUID]))
                          |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1006]=SUM(If (((([Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctMiscellaneous' OR [Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctTokens') OR [Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctChips') OR [Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctCanadianCoin') OR [
                               |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([OpenerDetails].[CurrencyGUID]) WITH PREFETCH)
                                    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join)
                                    |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[Openers].[IX_Openers_OneOpenerPerSession]), SEEK:([Openers].[OpenerGUID]=[Openers].[OpenerGUID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                                    |    |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[OpenerDetails].[IX_OpenerDetails_OpenerGUIDCurrencyGUID]), SEEK:([OpenerDetails].[OpenerGUID]=[Openers].[OpenerGUID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                                    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[Currencies].[PK_Currencies_CurrencyGUID]), SEEK:([Currencies].[CurrencyGUID]=[OpenerDetails].[CurrencyGUID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

The **bad** plan

```
       |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Expr1020] ASC, [Currencies].[Rank] ASC))
            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1020]=If ([Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctCanadianCash') then 1 else If ([Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctMiscellaneous') then 2 else If ([Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctTokens') then 3 else If ([Currencies].[Currency
                 |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Openers].[OpenerGUID]))
                      |--Filter(WHERE:((([Currencies].[IsActive]<>0 AND [Currencies].[OnOpener]<>0) AND ((((((([Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctUSCoin' OR [Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctMiscellaneousUS') OR [Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctUSCash') OR [Currenc
                      |    |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Currencies].[CurrencyGUID], [Openers].[OpenerGUID]) WITH PREFETCH)
                      |         |--Filter(WHERE:([Openers].[SessionGUID]=[@SessionGUID]))
                      |         |    |--Concatenation
                      |         |         |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join)
                      |         |         |    |--Table Spool
                      |         |         |    |    |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([Windows].[WindowGUID])=([Openers].[WindowGUID]), RESIDUAL:([Windows].[WindowGUID]=[Openers].[WindowGUID]))
                      |         |         |    |         |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[Windows].[IX_Windows_CageGUID]))
                      |         |         |    |         |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[Openers]))
                      |         |         |    |--Table Spool
                      |         |         |         |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[Currencies].[IX_Currencies_CurrencyType]))
                      |         |         |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Openers].[OpenerGUID]=NULL, [Openers].[SessionGUID]=NULL, [Windows].[UseChipDenominations]=NULL))
                      |         |              |--Nested Loops(Left Anti Semi Join)
                      |         |                   |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[Currencies].[IX_Currencies_CurrencyType]))
                      |         |                   |--Row Count Spool
                      |         |                        |--Table Spool
                      |         |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[OpenerDetails].[IX_OpenerDetails_OpenerGUIDCurrencyGUID]), SEEK:([OpenerDetails].[OpenerGUID]=[Openers].[OpenerGUID] AND [OpenerDetails].[CurrencyGUID]=[Cu
                      |--Hash Match(Cache, HASH:([Openers].[OpenerGUID]), RESIDUAL:([Openers].[OpenerGUID]=[Openers].[OpenerGUID]))
                           |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1006]=SUM([partialagg1034]), [Expr1007]=SUM([partialagg1035]), [Expr1008]=SUM([partialagg1036]), [Expr1009]=SUM([partialagg1037]), [Expr1010]=SUM([partialagg1038]), [Expr1011]=SUM([partialagg1039]
                                |--Nested Loops(Inner Join)
                                     |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([partialagg1034]=SUM(If (((([Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctMiscellaneous' OR [Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctTokens') OR [Currencies].[CurrencyType]='ctChips') OR [Currencies].[CurrencyType]='
                                     |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([OpenerDetails].[CurrencyGUID]) WITH PREFETCH)
                                     |         |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[OpenerDetails].[IX_OpenerDetails_OpenerGUIDCurrencyGUID]), SEEK:([OpenerDetails].[OpenerGUID]=[Openers].[OpenerGUID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                                     |         |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[Currencies].[PK_Currencies_CurrencyGUID]), SEEK:([Currencies].[CurrencyGUID]=[OpenerDetails].[CurrencyGUID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                                     |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([GrobManagementSystemLive].[dbo].[Openers].[IX_Openers_OneOpenerPerSession]), SEEK:([Openers].[OpenerGUID]=[Openers].[OpenerGUID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

The bad-one is eager spooling 6 million rows; the other one isn't.

> **Note:** This isn't a question about tuning a query. I have a query that runs lightning fast. I just want SQL Server to run fast from a stored procedure.

Comment: I notice every time you take a parameter and reassign it to another and then use it in a query later this can happen and as the answer suggests Optimize for @"someparamname" unknown can work.

Comment: As always, Erland Sommarskog's article is an excellent aid: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: Plus One for `sp_recompile` - Fixed my similar problem

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I found the problem, here's the script of the slow and fast versions of the stored procedure:

**`dbo.ViewOpener__RenamedForCruachan__Slow.PRC`**

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ViewOpener_RenamedForCruachan_Slow
    @SessionGUID uniqueidentifier
AS

SELECT *
FROM Report_Opener_RenamedForCruachan
WHERE SessionGUID = @SessionGUID
ORDER BY CurrencyTypeOrder, Rank
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

**`dbo.ViewOpener__RenamedForCruachan__Fast.PRC`**

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ViewOpener_RenamedForCruachan_Fast
    @SessionGUID uniqueidentifier 
AS

SELECT *
FROM Report_Opener_RenamedForCruachan
WHERE SessionGUID = @SessionGUID
ORDER BY CurrencyTypeOrder, Rank
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

If you didn't spot the difference, I don't blame you. The difference is not in the stored procedure at all. The difference that turns a fast 0.5 cost query into one that does an eager spool of 6 million rows:

**Slow:** `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`

**Fast:** `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`

---

This answer also could be made to make sense, since the view does have a join clause that says:

```
(table.column IS NOT NULL)
```

So there is some `NULL`s involved.

---

The explanation is further proved by returning to Query Analizer, and running

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

.

```
DECLARE @SessionGUID uniqueidentifier
SET @SessionGUID = 'BCBA333C-B6A1-4155-9833-C495F22EA908'
```

.

```
SELECT *
FROM Report_Opener_RenamedForCruachan
WHERE SessionGUID = @SessionGUID
ORDER BY CurrencyTypeOrder, Rank
```

And the query is slow.

---

So the problem **isn't** because the query is being run from a stored procedure. The problem is that Enterprise Manager's connection default option is `ANSI_NULLS off`, rather than `ANSI_NULLS on`, which is QA's default.

Microsoft acknowledges this fact in [KB296769](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296769) <sup>[archive](https://archive.ph/ERa5m)</sup>

> ### BUG: Cannot use SQL Enterprise Manager to create stored procedures containing linked server objects
>
> ### Cause
>
> By default, SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager sets ANSI_NULLS to OFF before creating a stored procedure.

The given workaround is to include the `ANSI_NULLS` option in the stored procedure dialog:

```
Set ANSI_NULLS ON
Go
Create Proc spXXXX as
....
```

Comment: I still don't understand how turning `ANSI_NULLS ON` makes such an enormous performance difference.

Comment: @Ek0nomik Because the `JOIN` clauses inside the view have different meaning when `ANSI_NULLS OFF`. Suddenly rows match, causing the optimizer to run the query completely differently. Imagine that rather than eliminating 99.9% of all rows, they suddenly return.

Comment: Note:  `ANSI_NULLS OFF`is deprecated and considered a bad practice

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql)"In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature."

Comment: Didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 514):

I had the same problem as the original poster but the quoted answer did not solve the problem for me. The query still ran really slow from a stored procedure.

I found another answer [here "Parameter Sniffing"](http://omnibuzz-sql.blogspot.com/2006/11/parameter-sniffing-stored-procedures.html), Thanks Omnibuzz. Boils down to using "local Variables" in your stored procedure queries, but read the original for more understanding, it's a great write up. e.g.

**Slow way:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOrderForCustomers(@CustID varchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM orders
    WHERE customerid = @CustID
END
```

**Fast way:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOrderForCustomersWithoutPS(@CustID varchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LocCustID varchar(20)
    SET @LocCustID = @CustID

    SELECT * 
    FROM orders
    WHERE customerid = @LocCustID
END
```

Doing this reduced my execution time from 5+ minutes to about 6-7 seconds.

Comment: +1 for the link, run into this before and nice to have the story.  Would believe this time it was select (@TOP) vs select (@LocalTop) .. really not sure why sniffing could help that one.

Comment: +1 But, this is very strange, and rise up a lot of questions like should we do this for all procedures and if not, when to do this?

Comment: Am I the only one who is baffled by this behavior?? Requiring local variables to be declared in order to prevent parameter sniffing?? Shouldn't SQL Server be smart enough to prevent this from happening in the first place? This just causes unnecessary code bloat by Microsoft's shortsighted design IMHO.

Comment: +1 Thank you!  Have been having this problem for weeks and this looks to be the fix.  Throwing this link here with some other possible fixes in the same line  http://realsqlguy.com/dont-get-slimed-bad-parameter-sniffing/

Comment: Should one consider WITH RECOMPILE instead?

Comment: @BennettDill `WITH RECOMPILE` did not make a difference for me, only the local parameters.

Comment: This can now be achieved using the query hint - OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@varA UNKNOWN, @varB UNKNOWN)

Comment: @I46kok The reason this happens is because the procedures query plan is being cached, along with the parameters that were passed to it. On subsequent calls, this query plan generated will be reused with new parameters. This can cause problems because if the data is unevenly distributed, one parameter can generate a sub-optimal plan vs. another. Using local variables essentially does the same as OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN because local variables cannot be sniffed. However, it still may cause issues with certain parameters, that's why OPTION (RECOMPILE) is better, in my opinion.

Comment: I had same problem, one query runs in 2 sec but in sp, had to kill after 42 min. Dont know why but using this solution sp now runs same 2 sec. Wow have no idea whats magic behind it. Can you explain this?

Comment: Throwing in another link that helped me understand everything that was going on as well as listing SEVERAL methods of combating it: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3257/different-approaches-to-correct-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/
The main decisions that should be made are whether you are ok caching a generic query plan to save some minor time/resources (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN/local variables), or don't use a cache at all (RECOMPILE)

Comment: This worked for me. Turned a 5min query into 5 seconds. I looked at the execution plan with and without param sniffing and running the same query outside of a stored proc. With the regular query and the SP using param sniffing, the execution plan shows a lot of parallelism. interestng reading here: https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. But this would work when you pass just one value as input parameter. How would you handle this when the Stored Procedure takes a list of values (comma - separated)?
For example, in MySQL, you have a function `find_in_set` which basically checks if the input parameter exist in the column and filters accordingly. I am facing a similar issue in MySQL and would appreciate it if someone can point me to right direction in case when I pass list of arguments in SP.

Comment: I guess this is still an issue in modern versions of SQL Server then?

Comment: I am facing the same behavior for MS SQL Server Standart 2016.... ((( Thanks man for the solution!

Comment: I'm really upset with this behavior. How this can make any sense at all? Can please somebody expert in SQL Server explain why this happens? This leaves me completely mute.  Thanks, Adam.

Comment: I've been battling this for years on  a query that would suddenly run slow after windows updates. I found if I ALTER the procedure that it sometimes fixed it. If it didn't fix it when I did it the first time, one of the subsequent retries would seem to, but then come back again next update. But today was different: nothing was working! I decided to do research AGAIN, and I ran across this post. AMAZING! It works! Time will tell if it stays (as an ALTER eventually worked before), but as of today, nothing else fixed it. I hope this really is the permanent solution. I will update if not!

Comment: Intro of local var, reduced SPROC execution time from 16+ minutes to 6 seconds. My trouble SPROC had a single smalldatetime param @a, and a simple if @a is null set @a = getdate()

Comment: @Dave Even if using a query hint fixes the issue, doesn't that mean that I would need to apply that hint to every place in my code that is calling the stored procedure? It seems much easier to apply a fix to the procedure itself.

Answer (score 28):

I was facing the same issue & this post was very helpful to me but none of the posted answers solved my specific issue. I wanted to post the solution that worked for me in hopes that it can help someone else.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24016676/814299

> At the end of your query, add OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@now UNKNOWN))

Answer (score 20):

Do this for your database. I have the same issue - it works fine in one database but when I copy this database to another using SSIS Import (not the usual restore), this issue happens to most of my stored procedures. So after googling some more, I found the [blog of Pinal Dave (which btw, I encountered most of his post and did help me a lot so thanks Pinal Dave)](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/01/31/sql-server-reindexing-database-tables-and-update-statistics-on-tables/).

I execute the below query on my database and it corrected my issue:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' DBCC DBREINDEX ('?', ' ', 80)"
GO
EXEC sp_updatestats
GO
```

Hope this helps. Just passing the help from others that helped me.

Comment: Just an FYI for future readers: `DBCC REINDEX` has been deprecated, so you should look for alternatives.

Comment: Fixed my issue, thanks (1m20s down to 2s!). Re: `DBCC DBREINDEX`, MS says : "This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Do not use this feature in new development work, and modify applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible. Use ALTER INDEX instead."

Comment: Don't know if this is the best answer but in my case sp_updatestats is all it took, so +1

Comment: ..yes and, don't forget that rebuilding indexes may take time and space so before you execute this on your production server make sure you can afford possible slowdown. I would suggest to look into REORGANIZE or REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON)

Comment: @Todd Menier sp_updatestats worked for me, still does not explain the difference in performance when you re-assign parameter to the local variable.

Comment: Had the same problem, reindex and update stats solved it for me too. We used this one:
`DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]) + '.' + name AS TableName
FROM sys.tables;
OPEN TableCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor
INTO @TableName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @TableName + N' REBUILD';
    EXEC (@sql);
    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor
    INTO @TableName;
END;
CLOSE TableCursor;
DEALLOCATE TableCursor;
GO
EXEC sp_updatestats;
GO`

Answer (score 6):

I was experiencing this problem. My query looked something like:

```
select a, b, c from sometable where date > '20140101'
```

My stored procedure was defined like:

```
create procedure my_procedure (@dtFrom date)
as
select a, b, c from sometable where date > @dtFrom
```

I changed the datatype to datetime and voila! Went from 30 minutes to 1 minute!

```
create procedure my_procedure (@dtFrom datetime)
as
select a, b, c from sometable where date > @dtFrom
```

Comment: Thanks A LOT Lee, this saved my day!

Here's how I get only the date part of a datetime field :

DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, table.field))

Comment: THIS Fixed my problem. I had column varchar(20) and my parameter was nvarchar(50), once I made the parameter type same as the column type - no more delays.

Answer (score 4):

This time you found your problem. If next time you are less lucky and cannot figure it out, you can use [plan freezing](http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2009/06/plan-freezing.html) and stop worrying about wrong execution plan.

Comment: According to that blog entry, plan freezing is only for MS SQL 2005 and up, so it wouldn't help the OP.

Comment: The problem was it was using the wrong query plan. i wouldn't want to freeze it to the wrong one.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried rebuilding the statistics and/or the indexes on the Report_Opener table. All the recomplies of the SP won't be worth anything if the stats still show data from when the database was first inauguarated.

The initial query itself works quickly because the optimiser can see that the parameter will never be null.  In the case of the SP the optimiser cannot be sure that the parameter will never be null.

Comment: Is there a way to indicate in a stored procedure declaration that i parameter cannot be null? And is it not something that would be fixed by sp_executesql?

Comment: In a word nope, not in 2000.  2005 added a query hint where you could provide an example value for a parameter, the optimiser would optimise as if it knew that parameter was always used.  Having said that I've generally found this sort of thing to be a statistics problem.

Comment: If it's a statistics problem, they does it work fine from QA when i run it ad-hoc, sp_executesql, exec(). And why do they all then run poorly when a stored procedure contains the ad-hoc sql, sp_executesql, exec() ?

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm usually against it (though in this case it seems that you have a genuine reason), have you tried providing any query hints on the SP version of the query? If SQL Server is preparing a different execution plan in those two instances, can you use a hint to tell it what index to use, so that the plan matches the first one?

For some examples, [you can go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258869.aspx).

EDIT: If you can post your query plan here, perhaps we can identify some difference between the plans that's telling.

SECOND: Updated the link to be SQL-2000 specific. You'll have to scroll down a ways, but there's a second titled "Table Hints" that's what you're looking for.

THIRD: The "Bad" query seems to be ignoring the [IX_Openers_SessionGUID] on the "Openers" table - any chance adding an INDEX hint to force it to use that index will change things?

Comment: The most useful query hints in that reference are not available on SQL 2000 which is the version in question here.

Comment: Additionally, what hints are needed? SQL Server is able to figure it out no problem when i run it ad-hoc.

Comment: Sure, and that's always been my experience too. However, in this case, he's saying it's coming up with a totally different exec plan. Maybe there's an index that's utilized ad-hoc, but for some reason is being ignored in the proc. He can force SQL Server to use the index with the  "INDEX" hint.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably unlikely, but given that your observed behaviour is unusual it needs to be checked and no-one else has mentioned it.

*Are you **absolutely** sure that all objects are owned by dbo and you don't have a rogue copies owned by yourself or a different user present as well?*

Just occasionally when I've seen odd behaviour it's because there was actually two copies of an object and which one you get depends on what is specified and who you are logged on as.  For example it is perfectly possible to have two copies of a view or procedure with the same name but owned by different owners - a situation that can arise where you are not logged onto the database as a dbo and forget to specify dbo as object owner when you create the object.

In note that in the text you are running some things without specifying owner, eg

```
sp_recompile ViewOpener
```

if for example there where two copies of viewOpener present owned by dbo and [some other user] then which one you actually recompile if you don't specify is dependent upon circumstances.  Ditto with the Report_Opener view - if there where two copies (and they could differ in specification or execution plan) then what is used depends upon circumstances - and as you do not specify owner it is perfectly possible that your adhoc query might use one and the compiled procedure might use use the other.

As I say, it's probably unlikely but it is possible and should be checked because your issues could be that you're simply looking for the bug in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound silly and seems obvious from the name SessionGUID, but is the column a uniqueidentifier on Report_Opener? If not, you may want to try casting it to the correct type and give it a shot or declare your variable to the correct type.

The plan created as part of the sproc may work unintuitively and do an internal cast on a large table.

Comment: It is not. But i have seen performance problems with a where clause that was comparing a `varchar` column with an `nvarchar` value (E.g. `WHERE CustomerName = N'zrendall'`). SQL Server had to up convert every column value to an `nvarchar` before the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I've got another idea. What if you create this table-based function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION tbfSelectFromView
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @SessionGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Report_Opener
    WHERE SessionGUID = @SessionGUID
    ORDER BY CurrencyTypeOrder, Rank
)
GO
```

And then selected from it using the following statement (even putting this in your SP):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbfSelectFromView(@SessionGUID)
```

It looks like what's happening (which everybody has already commented on) is that SQL Server just makes an assumption somewhere that's wrong, and maybe this will force it to correct the assumption. I hate to add the extra step, but I'm not sure what else might be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

-- Here is the solution:

```
create procedure GetOrderForCustomers(@CustID varchar(20))

as

begin

select * from orders

where customerid = ISNULL(@CustID, '')

end
```

-- That's it

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found was that the parameter was not declared with the same type as the actual column definition. Causing SQL Server to try to find the fastest way = Nested Loops.

ex. DECLARE MyParameter nvarchar(50)
Actual column: varchar(8)