# Slow as a stored procedure, fast as a query - not parameter sniffing

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

I have a confused problem. I have a SP that include a query with few JOINs (2 of them are LEFT JOINs). The SP take 10 seconds, and if I execute the query as a query - it's take 200 ms...

This is not parameter sniffing issue: even if I clean the cache and execute the SP with only one set of parameters - still slow.
I also try to execute the SP with recompile, and to add option (recompile) in the query in the SP - still slow.

I try those links:

- [Query runs fast, but runs slow in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995386/query-runs-fast-but-runs-slow-in-stored-procedure)
- [SQL Server: Query fast, but slow from procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440944/sql-server-query-fast-but-slow-from-procedure)
- [Query times out when executed from web, but super-fast when executed from SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248112/query-times-out-when-executed-from-web-but-super-fast-when-executed-from-ssms)

I have to mention also that:

1. 2 parameters of the SP are table type.
2. There is no dynamic SQL in the SP.

So - what is the story here???

This is the SP code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spr_spr]
    @ListOfIDs dbo.tt_IDsList READONLY, -- (one column - ID)
    @ListOfTwoIDs dbo.tt_TwoIDsRelationList READONLY, -- (two columns - FirstID, SecondID)
    @SomeID int = NULL
AS

IF @SomeID IS NULL 
    SELECT  ..... , 
            cast ( (CASE WHEN le.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bit) as HasLinkedID 
    FROM        @ListOfIDs ids
    JOIN        dbo.tbl1 ra             ON  ids.ID = ra.RR_RowID                                         
    JOIN        dbo.tbl2 rr             ON  ra.RR_RowID = rr.RowID
    JOIN        dbo.tbl3 res            ON  res.tbl3ID = ra.tbl3ID
    JOIN        dbo.tbl4 cal            ON  cal.ObjectID = rr.ObjectID 
    JOIN        @ListOfTwoIDs IdsRel    ON  cal.FirstID = IdsRel.FirstID
                                        AND res.SecondID = IdsRel.SecondID
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.tbl5 p              ON  ra.tbl5ID = p.tbl5ID 
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.tbl6 le             ON  le.tbl6ID = ra.tbl6ID

ELSE
    .... -- same query with one change
```

Comment: Can we see the SP code?

Comment: agreed with @jyparask, best is provide with your code for us to consider =)

Comment: Accepted answer from the first link you provided should do the trick. Just copy your input parameters into local variables and work with them instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute the query as a query"? Can you show the code that runs fast?

Comment: The code that runs fast is the same code that run as a query, not from the SP execution.

Comment: @itaigitt - So the only difference is variables vs parameters?

Comment: When was the last time the SP was recompiled? If it's old, it may not be using the latest indexes.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
CREATE TABLE #ListOfIDs (ID int)
insert into #ListOfIDs (ID) select ID from @ListOfIDs 

CREATE TABLE #ListOfTwoIDs (FirstID int, SecondID int)
insert into #ListOfTwoIDs (FirstID, SecondID) select FirstID, SecondID from @ListOfTwoIDs
```

I guess that the issue was with the table-types parameters, but I still don't understand why and what...