# MySQL - Fast query but slow Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, query-performance

I know this question has been discussed quite a lot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440944/sql-server-query-fast-but-slow-from-procedure). But I have a particular case when I need to pass a list of parameters (comma - separated) which prevents me to have a local variable declared and used for input parameter.

As pointed out in the above discussion, it is suggested to declare a local variable and assign the parameters to this variable. However, what should I do in case my parameter is of type `Text` and can be comma - separated list?

For example -

```
CREATE DEFINER=`Admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `MyReport`(
    p_myparameter_HK Text
)
BEGIN
SELECT
*
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
(find_in_set(MyTable.column_HK, p_myparameter_HK) <> 0 OR MyTable.column_HK IS NULL)
;

END
```

Performance:

> Query

If I just run the query - 300 ms

> Stored Procedure

```
CALL MyReport('0000_abcd_fake_000')
```

This procedure keeps running endlessly.

My question is, how can I disable `parameter sniffling` and use local variable instead of `find_in_set` to match the query performance.

Comment: It is usually not useful to reference a non-MySQL reference when discussing a MySQL topic.  There are _many_ differences.  (MariaDB and Percona are OK.)

Comment: @RickJames Will edit the tag. Thanks!

Comment: The `OR` may also be inhibiting performance.

Comment: @RickJames But I need that for  condition when the value doesn't exist.

Comment: How many rows in MyTable?

Comment: @RickJames The full query produces about 3-3.5 Million rows. The main table has about 1 million rows.

Comment: I'm confused -- How can the query produce more rows than the table?  Have you left some critical parts out?

Comment: The source table has value X (say). Now this `X` can be in multiple languages. So when I join those it basically produces all records with `X` and it's language of origin. The data is actually of a User and his/her exams. The Users can appear in one or multiple languages for a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The times that I have needed to pass an arbitrary list of things to a Stored Procedure, I did it this way:

- `CREATE` (or already have) a `TABLE` for passing the info in.  Both the caller and the Procedure know the name of the procedure.  (Or it could be passed in, but adds some messy "prepare-executes".)
- Do a bulk `INSERT` into that table.  (`INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (...), (..), ...;`)
- Perform `JOINs` or whatever to use the table efficiently.

In my case, the extra effort was worth it.

Comment: Are you saying that I need go create a temporary table with parameter values and then join with the result set?

Comment: @Hello.World - Is there an index on `column_HK`?  What is its datatype?  (Or simply provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

Comment: The HK is basically SHA2(column, 256). Also, all _HKs have indexes.

Comment: @Hello.World - That gets into a different dimension -- How big (gigabytes) is the table?  How big is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM?

Comment: @Hello.World - And why are you using hashes?  Are the things being hashed big text/blob columns?

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size is 2.5G. RAM is 16GB. Hash keys are primary keys for warehouse tables that I am using. And their datatype is varchar(36)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195726/discussion-between-hello-world-and-rick-james).