# Stored procedure was fine but then became extremly slow

Tags: sql-server

My stored procedure was taking around 10 seconds, but suddenly (for unknown reasons) it became so slow (taking 9 minutes).

I did not do any changes at all that may cause the delay.

I wonder if someone can tell why it is so slow.

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    P.PtsID, P.PtsCode, P.PtsName, 
    FORMAT(P.DOB, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS DOB, P.Gender, V.VisitID, V.VisitType, 
    FORMAT(V.VisitDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS VisitDate,  
    FORMAT(V.DischargeDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS DischargeDate, 
    R.RepID, R.RepDate, R.RepType, R.RepDesc
FROM
    Patients P 
INNER JOIN 
    Visits V ON P.PtsID = V.PtsID 
INNER JOIN 
    Reps R ON R.PtsID = P.PtsID AND R.VisitID = V.VisitID
WHERE 
    (P.Deleted = 0 AND V.Deleted = 0 AND R.Deleted = 0)
    AND (P.PtsName LIKE '%'+TRIM(@PtsName)+'%' OR TRIM(@PtsName) = '')
    AND (P.PtsCode LIKE '%'+TRIM(@PtsNo)+'%' OR TRIM(@PtsNo) = '')
    AND (R.RepText LIKE '%'+TRIM(@RepText)+'%' OR TRIM(@RepText) = '')
    AND (TRIM(@RepCode) = '' OR R.RepID IN (SELECT RepID 
                                            FROM tags 
                                            WHERE tag = 'XXX' 
                                              AND Deleted = 0
                                              AND code IN (SELECT value 
                                                           FROM string_split(@RepCode,','))))
```

and this is the execution plan

[image]

When I execute the script as an ad-hoc query, not as stored procedure, it is very fast.

**Edit**

Here is my actual execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByPLltcZD

Thanks

Comment: The table got to big. You have to use indexes.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič the table has 3000 records

Comment: Can you please paste your actual execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ ?

Comment: Your statistics/estimates are completly wrong, see `900 of 2 - 45.000%` , Can it be [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) ?  Please share the exection plan as @marc_s suggested. Your query might not be sargable (like % %) . Changing the IN to EXISTS may improve performance a little.

Comment: Answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440944/sql-server-query-fast-but-slow-from-procedure

Comment: @CyrilG. Thanks mate, that solved the problem :) put it as an answer I will mark it

Comment: Answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440944/sql-server-query-fast-but-slow-from-procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So purely bassed on the execution plan.

#### Statistics

In your exection plan you can see the actual numbers and estimates are far apart.
This can have multiple causes.

- Out of date statistics and indexes. Try rebuilding indexes and updating statistics

  - Updating stats: `EXEC sp_updatestats` (this might take some time and resources, so if its a production server, do it out of the office hours / batch job windows.)
- Parameter sniffig can also cause wrong estimations. You can expirment with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` or `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` to test if this is the case.
- [201 Bucket Problem](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/07/the-201-buckets-problem-part-1-why-you-still-dont-get-accurate-estimates/)

#### Query optimization

When you write `IN(subquery)` and you have a key lookup, like you have. You are going to have a bad time. For every row returned from the index (`NonClusteredIndex-code`) the engine needs to access the clustered index to retrieve the `RepID` one-by-one = Painfully slow when it's multiple rows (In your case: 430.474.500 rows).

You can change this by using `EXISTS`, in your example:

```
SELECT 
    P.PtsID, P.PtsCode, P.PtsName, 
    FORMAT(P.DOB, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS DOB, P.Gender, V.VisitID, V.VisitType, 
    FORMAT(V.VisitDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS VisitDate,  
    FORMAT(V.DischargeDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS DischargeDate, 
    R.RepID, R.RepDate, R.RepType, R.RepDesc
FROM
    Patients P 
INNER JOIN 
    Visits V ON P.PtsID = V.PtsID 
INNER JOIN 
    Reps R ON R.PtsID = P.PtsID AND R.VisitID = V.VisitID
WHERE 
    (P.Deleted = 0 AND V.Deleted = 0 AND R.Deleted = 0)
    AND (P.PtsName LIKE '%'+TRIM(@PtsName)+'%' OR TRIM(@PtsName) = '')
    AND (P.PtsCode LIKE '%'+TRIM(@PtsNo)+'%' OR TRIM(@PtsNo) = '')
    AND (R.RepText LIKE '%'+TRIM(@RepText)+'%' OR TRIM(@RepText) = '')
    AND (TRIM(@RepCode) = '' OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                            FROM tags 
                                            WHERE tag = 'XXX' 
                                              AND Deleted = 0
                                              AND tags.RepId = r.RepId
                                              AND code IN (SELECT value 
                                                           FROM string_split(@RepCode,','))))
```

#### Index optimizations

If you are still suffering from the Key lookup you may want to change the index, so it also has `RepId` or [include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns?view=sql-server-ver15#to-create-an-index-with-nonkey-columns-1) it.

You still have 2 other key lookups. You could also solve this with an `INCLUDE` on the indexes but only if it makes sense. (Can they be used for other queries, is the current query executing frequently, ...)

---

*Doing the trims and concatenation and storing them in a separate variable may give you some minor improvements.*

---

### Wait stats

The following wait stats where also included in the execution plan.

```
<WaitStats>
  <Wait WaitType="RESERVED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT" WaitTimeMs="1018" WaitCount="2694600"/>
  <Wait WaitType="SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD" WaitTimeMs="514" WaitCount="159327"/>
  <Wait WaitType="ASYNC_NETWORK_IO" WaitTimeMs="63" WaitCount="5"/>
  <Wait WaitType="MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT" WaitTimeMs="25" WaitCount="14639"/>
</WaitStats>
```

[RESERVED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/reserved_memory_allocation_ext/) and [MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/memory_allocation_ext/) but there is no issue with wait stats.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another post: [SQL Server: Query fast, but slow from procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440944/sql-server-query-fast-but-slow-from-procedure)

You can use the following workaround

```
Slow: SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

Fast: SET ANSI_NULLS ON
```